# Where does the king Sudas of the Dasrajna war fit in the Lunar Dynasty?

Tags: vedas, chandravansh, genealogy, bharata

I was reading about the  [Daśarājñá  War](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv07018.htm) mentioned in the Vedas and came to know that the winner was a King called Sudas who belonged to the Bharat lineage. That would imply that he descended from the Raja Bharat who is also the ancestor of the Kauravs and Pandavs.

I want to know where does Sudas fit in the Lunar Dynasty or Chandra-Vansha. Was he before the Pandavs or after them? It would be great to know his exact position in the genealogy.

Comment: We should not mix up the stories of Rig Veda with that of EPICs like Mahabharata or Ramayana.  The Solar and Moon dynasties that were mentioned in EPICs may be different from the kings mentioned in Rig Veda.  Everyone descended from Manu and Manu was given knowledge by Indra.  So we may call the kings of Rig Veda as descendants of Indra. :-)  @Viraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Garuna Puarna](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122620.html) there was a king Sudasa from Bharat lineage who rules at panchala.

> The son of Ainila was Dushmanta, who by his wife Shakuntala, had a son named **Bharata**. The son of Bharata was Vitatha, whose son was Manyu, whose son was Nara, whose son was Samkriti, who was the father of Gardha. The son of Gardha was Amanyu, whose son was Shini. The mighty Nara, the son of Manyu had another son named Urukshaya. The son of Urukshaya was Trayaruni, whose son was Vyuhakshetra, whose son was Suhotra, who had three sons Hasti, Ajamida and Dvimida. The son of Hasti was Purumida, and the son of Ajamida was Kanva. Medhatithi sprang from this Kauva, who was the progenitor of the Kanvayana clan of Brahmanas. Ajamida had another son named Vrihadishu, who was the father of Vrihatdhanu. The son of Vrihatdhanu was Vrihatkarma, whose son was Jayadratha, whose son was Vishvajit, whose son was Senajit, whose son was Ruchirashva, who was the father of Prithusena.
>
> Puru was the son of Prithusena, whose son was Dvipa, whose son was Samara. Prithusena had another son named Sukriti. The son of Sukriti was Vibhraja, whose son was Ashvaha. The said Ashvaha had a son by his wife Kriti, named Brahmadatta, whose son was Vishvaksen. Dvimidha, the sun of Suhotra had a son named Yamina. The son of Yamina was Dhritimana, whose son was Satyadhriti, whose son was Dridhamuni. The son of Dridhamuni was Suparshva, whose son was Sannati. The son of Sannati was Kritu, whose son was Ugrayudha, whose son was Kshema, whose son was Sudhira, whose son was Puranjaya, who was the father of Viduratha.
>
> Ajamida had a wife named Nalini, who gave birth to Nila. The son of Nila was Shanti, whose son was Sushanti, whose son was Puru, whose son was Arka, whose son was Haryashva, who was the father of Mukula. **This Mukula became the ruler of the country of Panchala.** He had five sons named Yuvanira, Vrihadbhanu, Kampilla, Srinjaya and Sharadvana, This Sharadvana was firmly devoted to Vishnu. Sharadvana begat a son on Ahalya, who was called Divodasa, the socond. Divodasa had a son named Shatananda. Satyadhriti was the son of Shatananda. Satyadhriti lost control over his senses at the sight of the nymph Urvasi, and a son named Kripa and a daughter named Kripri were born out of his emitted seed. Kripri was married to Dronacharyya, and Ashvathvama was the fruit of this union.
>
> The son of Divodasa was Mitrayu, whose son was Chyavana, whose son was **Sudasa**, who was the father of Saudasa.

Even King Sudasa of Dasarjana war said to be the ruler of southern Punjab or Panachal.

Comment: Great this is helpful but I doubt if Panchal was in Punjab. Wiki gives its location to the east of Kurus while this Sudas of the Dasrajna battle was in the west.